# Trying to install vc++ redistributable 2015 on a fresh windows 10 install

Tags: windows, visual-c++

as the title states, having wiped a machine (it's offline, and is not allowed to connect to any network for STIGs) using a windows 10 2h1 fresh install with absolutely nothing else on the machine, it will error out when trying to install a vc++ redistributable on there. Windows sdk. really almost any additional piece of windows software that could be used for development purposes.

The machine this log comes from is old (2009) but that's not really relevant -- i have 2 other machines, one from 2022 and one from 2019 that, when given the same build of windows (no choice in that, it must be this build) will reject the vc++ redistro the same way, with the same error, producing almost identical logs.  The error in question is 0x800900009 "invalid flags." No one on any Microsoft forum has given me a response that wasn't "failed install try again" or some version thereof.  Log's attached.

Additional information: this is done from an admin account, using administrative privileges, always raising privs whenever asked (and explicitly even when UN-asked).  There is LITERALLY nothing else on the machine other than this version of windows.  15 seconds later, trying to install this redistro, we get the error.

Have also tried their troubleshooting tool, it finds absolutely nothing wrong, but wants to connect to the internet to do additional troubleshooting, which it cannot be allowed to do.

I know there is an 80070570 in there "partially installed or corrupted" but this is after many attempts, many wipes, and many reinstalls. It's also a red herring -- the 2015 redistro (3rd time i've downloaded it) comes directly from microsoft's website, from this link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685, and i can state categorically that on a freshly installed system the log produced will be identical.

```
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:27]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v10.0 (Build 19044: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{29AE0051-88F8-4ED7-A6F9-7EA37A6B11A3}\vc_redist.x86.exe, cmdline: ''
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20191213220127.log'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{29AE0051-88F8-4ED7-A6F9-7EA37A6B11A3}\vc_redist.x86.exe'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\Desktop\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{29AE0051-88F8-4ED7-A6F9-7EA37A6B11A3}\'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]w120: Detected partially cached package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, invalid payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, reason: 0x80070570
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]w120: Detected partially cached package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, invalid payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623, reason: 0x80070570
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, cached: Partial
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:28]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20191213220127_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86_rollback.log'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20191213220127_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20191213220127_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86_rollback.log'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20191213220127_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:41]i300: Apply begin
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\.be\VC_redist.x86.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\VC_redist.x86.exe'
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, version: 14.0.23026.0
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to calculate hash for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to verify hash of payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e310: Failed to verify payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, error: 0x80090009, delete: Yes
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to cache payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[11AC:1188][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e314: Failed to cache payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 from working path: C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, error: 0x80090009.
[11AC:1188][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e349: Application requested retry of payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, encountered error: 0x80090009. Retrying...
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to calculate hash for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to verify hash of payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e310: Failed to verify payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, error: 0x80090009, delete: Yes
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to cache payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[11AC:1188][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e314: Failed to cache payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 from working path: C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, error: 0x80090009.
[11AC:1188][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e349: Application requested retry of payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, encountered error: 0x80090009. Retrying...
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to calculate hash for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to verify hash of payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e310: Failed to verify payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, error: 0x80090009, delete: Yes
[0B18:04AC][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed to cache payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[11AC:1188][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e314: Failed to cache payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 from working path: C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, error: 0x80090009.
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:46]e000: Error 0x80090009: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i352: Removing cached bundle: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\
[0B18:147C][2019-12-13T22:01:46]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[11AC:1224][2019-12-13T22:01:47]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80090009, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: Wild guess, hopefully someone else has better intel:  the hash errors might be from missing root certificates?  Old Windows versions without updates can have problems with verifying Authenticode signatures so maybe it's a similar issue?

Comment: Don't know anything about that -- is this something that a right out of the box fresh windows install doesn't have?  How would one check?

Comment: Old windows version = missing newer root certs from DigiCert, etc. used for code signing apps and HTTPS connections.  Windows Update would add the certs, without that you'd need to get them from Digicert, etc. instead.  For the packages with the hash errors, can you righht-click, properties, look at Digital Signature?   Note this is just guessing though.

Comment: If its the windows version, then why would windows act differently, from the same install (10 2h1) on different machiens, all of which are air-gapped?

Comment: re: digicerts, yes, it has two. .  digest algorithms, sha1, sha256, from microsoft.

Comment: For the packages where the hash fails, when you look at the details for their digital signatures, does Windows say the sig is OK and does the certificate path look OK?  Again, this is guessing.  We've had issues in the past with our app because it uses windows APIs to validate its signature to prevent tampering, and people with Windows Update turned off or broken have had the API fail for a perfectly valid cert where their OS was missing the DigiCert root certificate.

Comment: I wish i could include an image.  But each sig has the following rows:   digest algorithm, digest encrypted algorithm, authenticated attributes: content type, message digest, unauthenticated attributes: counter sign.  That's it. no path to speak of.

Comment: That's the second nested details.  At the top of the popup should be a "certification path" tab that shows the chain of certificates, typically 3-4 entries in the chain including the root certificate at the top.  Ahh, I see.  Files in C: > windows > system32 use a "Microsoft Windows PCA" cert that has no certification path and is a root cert that has no parent certs.  Look at the cert for some non-Microsoft app to see the chain I was talking about.    Is what you're seeing here a Microsoft cert with no cert path tab?  And does properties say "this digital signature is OK"?

Comment: Afraid i don't see such a set of options.  On the details tab, I've got file description, type, file version, product name, product version, copyright ,size, date modified, language and original filename.  No certification path or anything like that.    From the "properties" option there's only 6 tabs.  security, details, previous versions, general, compatibility and digital signatures.

Comment: I mean nested under Digital Signatures.  If you look at a signed non-Microsoft app and choose Digital Signatures you'll see a Details button.  After clicking that you'll see tabs General, Advanced and a View Certificate button.  After you click View Certificate you finally get to a second popup with 3 tabs General, Details, Certification Path.

Comment: Fraid i don't.  Does this need admin permissions? after following that trail i only see general and advanced.

Comment: On that pop, if you click on the cert is there a View Details button?

Comment: ah, i see, yes.    General, details, certification path, is that the set of data that you're interested in?

Comment: Yes, like I said just a guess but does the certification path have any red "x" or comments about unknown or invalid certs or not being able to validate all of them?

Comment: No red x's anywhere here, no.

Comment: Sorry, that was my only suggestion.  I searched "Failed to verify hash of payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86" out of curiosity and in one case the package had a hidden online requirement to fetch some files, in another it was a bad package from Microsoft, but neither looked like it was your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt, nonethless. Yeah i've been all over creation trying to find anything about this and of the 6 or so different forum posts on various microsoft locations including all of the dev forums, i've gotten nothing.  We have a support ticket open with them now since its installing microsoft software on microsoft windows with no other confounding factors, we'll see if they have anything at all to say.  I'm not holding my breath.